# 301 Redirects htaccess - Keep one url parameter, remove the rest and update URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create some 301 redirect rules, but just don't have the syntax understanding to make it work. I've seen lots of examples, but can't get my specific case to work.

Old URL sample:

```
/new-products-display.cfm?asset=ION2810040N&c=ION&s=281
```

Redirect to new URL structure plus asset parameter (remove additional query parameters)

```
https://example.com/inventory/product-display/?asset=ION2810040N
```

Below is my current best try, but I just can't get it to work quite right.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^asset=([^&]+)&c=([^&]+)&s=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /inventory/product-display/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(asset=[^&]+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^new-products-display\.cfm$ /inventory/product-display/?%1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your quick help!!!